# limit and offset on joined table

Tags: sql, join, limit

i have 2 table **category** and **items**, i want display it descending order by categoy id with limt and offset

category table:

```
  a   |  b  
 -----+-----
    1 | cat1
    2 | cat2
    3 | cat3
    4 | cat4
    5 | cat5
    6 | cat6
```

when run this sql code

```
SELECT  c.* ,f.Amount, f.Item FROM item_table f
   LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT * FROM category c LIMIT '.$offset.', 3
   )
 AS c ON f.cat_id = c.id ORDER BY c.id desc
```

it return me like this

```
  a   |  b   | items
 -----+-------------
    3 | cat3 | item,item...
    2 | cat2 | item,item...
    1 | cat1 | item,item...
```

but i want it return me

```
  a   |  b   | items
 -----+-------------
    6 | cat6 | item,item...
    4 | cat4 | item,item...
    5 | cat5 | item,item...
```

how i can do it?

Comment: are you using `mysql` or `oracle` RDBMS??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add order by clause inside subquery.

```
SELECT  c.* ,f.Amount, f.Item FROM item_table f
   LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT * FROM category c 
   ORDER BY c.id desc
   LIMIT '.$offset.', 3
   )
 AS c ON f.cat_id = c.id
 ORDER BY c.id desc
```

Comment: i doubt this, subquery doesnt allow order by AFAIK!

Comment: If he is using mysql its ok.I saw the `limit` keyword and thought he is using mysql.